# Unsure how to send a json object from the same page by ajax to another page

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I know there is a lot of posts on this subject but most of them refer to external JSON files.

I actually want to send the JSON Object that is mentioned on the same page by AJAX to a PHP page and out put all the sent JSON values to the PHP page in a h1 tag how can this be done?

This is my code example.

**index.php**

```
<script>

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){

document.querySelector('#submit').addEventListener('click',fx);

function fx(){

//<JSON data>

var data = {
    firstName: "Jon",
    lastName: "Smith",
    age: 24
};

//</JSON data>

//<AJAX>
var xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange= function(){

if(xhr.readyState == 4){

document.querySelector('#output').innerHTML= xhr.responseText;

}
}

xhr.open('POST','x');
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.send(data);
//</AJAX>
}

});

</script>

<button id='submit'>Send JSON data</button>

<div id='output'></div>
```

**x.php**

```
<?php
//???
?>

<h1><?php //show all the sent JSON object values in this h1 tag ?></h1>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn the object into a JSON string with `JSON.stringify()` and send it, then on the php script you decode the JSON into an object or array with `json_decode()`.

the javascript

```
var data = {
    firstName: "Jon",
    lastName: "Smith",
    age: 24
};
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(data); 

// additions to your xhttp send section
xhttp.open("POST", "x.php", true); // setting the third parameter to 'true' make the ajax call asynchronous, remove that if you want a synchronous request
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.send("jsonstr=myJSON");
```

the php

```
$jsonstr = $_POST["jsonstr"];
$data = json_decode($jsonstr); // if you want $data to be an object

echo $data->firstName; // Jon
echo $data->lastName; // Smith
echo $data->age; // 24
```

or

```
$jsonstr = $_POST["jsonstr"];
$data = json_decode($jsonstr,true); // if you want $data to be an array

echo $data[firstName]; // Jon
echo $data[lastName]; // Smith
echo $data[age]; // 24
```

In x.php you should be able to set the heading like this:

```
<h1><?php echo $data->firstName.' '.$data->lastName.' '.$data->age;?></h1>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but its showing errors in the php part I put this <h1><?php echo $var = json_decode($jsonstr);  ?></h1> and it gave me this error  Notice: Undefined variable: jsonstr in C:\xampp\path\x.php on line 1

Comment: You need to catch the posted data on the php page and save it into a variable named $jsonstr or any other name as you prefer.

Comment: But what is x refering to the $_POST['X']; this is what I put

Comment: <?php

echo $jsonstr= $_POST['firstName'];

?>

<h1><?php echo $var = json_decode($jsonstr);  ?></h1>

Comment: Undefined index: firstName

Comment: Thank you @John.M you are a life saver. I been trying to figure this out for a while now and your example makes me understand how JSON can work in situations like this thank you.

Comment: There is no reason to use a URL-encoded form value.  You could just post the JSON as `application/json`.  More importantly, your example is wide open to XSS attacks.  Never concatenate arbitrary data into the context of HTML without escaping it with `htmlspecialchars()` or equivalent.

Answer (score -1):

Try this example.

**index.php**

```
<script>

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){

document.querySelector('#submit').addEventListener('click',sendUserInfo);

function sendUserInfo(){

//<JSON data>

var user_info = {
    first_name: "John",
    last_name: "Smith",
    age: 24
};

//</JSON data>

var user_info_json_object= 'user_info_json_object='+JSON.stringify(user_info); 

//<AJAX>
var xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange= function(){

if(xhr.readyState == 4){

document.querySelector('#output').innerHTML= xhr.responseText;

}
}

xhr.open('POST','x');
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.send(user_info_json_object);
//</AJAX>
}

});

</script>

<button id='submit'>Send JSON data</button>

<div id='output'></div>
```

**x.php**

```
<?php

$user_info_json_object = json_decode($_POST['user_info_json_object']);

$first_name= $user_info_json_object->first_name;
$last_name= $user_info_json_object->last_name;
$age= $user_info_json_object->age;

?>

<h1><?php echo $first_name; ?></h1>
<h1><?php echo $last_name; ?></h1>
<h1><?php echo $age; ?></h1>
```

Comment: I tried out your example as well and your example is also good as well but I have to give the best answer award to John.M because he was the one that helped me out first but thank you for trying to help me out to.

Comment: This encoding isn't complete.  In any case, the extra wrap with the URL-encoded form data is unnecessary.  You can just post the JSON.  Also, your code is open to XSS attacks.  Never concatenate arbitrary data into HTML.  You must escape it with `htmlspecialchars()` (or equivalent) first.